# R text mining - dealing with plurals

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm learning text mining in R and have had pretty good success. But I am stuck on how to deal with plurals. i.e. I want "nation" and "nations" to be counted as the same word and ideally "dictionary" and "dictionaries" to be counted as the same word.

```
x <- '"nation" and "nations" to be counted as the same word and ideally "dictionary" and "dictionaries" to be counted as the same word.'
```

Comment: When asking a question on SO, you are requested to provide (1) a sample data, (2) the list of packages you are using, (3) a code others can copy and paste to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have a look at this great GitHub packages by Bob Rudis (@hrbrmstr) https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pluralize

Comment: `SnowballC::wordStem` might be of some use here.

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution.  Here I use the pacman package to make the solution self contained:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
p_load_gh('hrbrmstr/pluralize')
p_load(quanteda)

x <- '"nation" and "nations" to be counted as the same word and ideally "dictionary" and "dictionaries"'
singularize(unlist(tokenize(x)))

##  [1] "\""         "nation"     "\""         "and"        "\""         "nation"     "\""        
##  [8] "to"         "be"         "counted"    "a"          "the"        "same"       "word"      
## [15] "and"        "ideally"    "\""         "dictionary" "\""         "and"        "\""        
## [22] "dictionary" "\""
```

Answer (score 1):

The SemNetCleaner package has a singularize function. It's slower than the pluralize package but its handling of nouns is better, I find. For example, Mars is not converted into Mar.