# Removing duplicate words in R and clustering similar words in r

Tags: r

I have this table in R.In this table the data in measure column "Zero-Loss Condensate Drain
Zero Loss Condensate Drain, Zero-Loss Condensate Drains " and "Wi-Fi Thermostat
Wi-Fi thermostats " is same but R treats this different and count differently. I want that Wi-Fi Thermostat and Wi-Fi thermostats should be treated same and give count 4 not 1,2,1 respectively. Similar results I want for Zero   Zero Loss Condensate Drain.

| measure | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| Thermostatic Radiator Valves (TRVs) | 45 |
| Smart Thermostatic Radiator Enclosure | 42 |
| Smart Thermostats | 4 |
| Thermostatic radiator valves | 3 |
| Wi-Fi Enabled Thermostats | 2 |
| Wi-Fi Thermostats | 1 |
| Smart Thermostat | 2 |
| Thermostatic and Float Steam Traps | 1 |
| Thermostatic Radiator Valves | 2 |
| Dual Fuel Thermostat | 1 |
| Programmable Setback Thermostats | 1 |
| Wi-Fi Thermostat | 1 |
| Wi-Fi thermostats | 2 |
| Zero-Loss Condensate Drain | 1 |
| Zero Loss Condensate Drain | 1 |
| Zero-Loss Condensate Drains | 2 |

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_NY<-trimws(NY$`Eligible measures`)
df_NY<-gsub("-"," ",df_NY)
stringr::str_to_title(df_NY)
df_NY<-sort(table(measure=unlist(strsplit(df_NY,";"))), decreasing = TRUE)
df_NY<-as.data.frame(df_NY)
df_NY %>% 
  mutate(helper = toupper(measure),
         helper = ifelse(str_ends(helper, 'S'), substring(helper,1, nchar(helper)-1), helper))%>%
  group_by(helper) %>%
  mutate(measure = first(measure)) %>% 
  group_by(measure) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>% 
  arrange(-Freq)
```

I ran this code for the above table but not getting desired result. For example ouput is Standard Fryers 4 Steamer 4 Steamers 4 Window\nReplacements 4 Bi level Controls 4 Full Size Convection Ovens 4 Low Flow Pre Rinse Spray Valve 3 Wi Fi Enabled Thermostats 3 Wi Fi Thermostats 3 Thermodynamic Steam Traps 1 Zero Loss Condensate Drain 1 Zero Loss Condensate Drains 2

But I want Steamers and Steamer should be treated as same and give output 8 instead of 4 repectively

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283624/removing-duplicate-words-in-a-string-in-r

Comment: [on plurals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938023/r-text-mining-dealing-with-plurals), and you might dput(df_NY) for good measure.

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg